# Iterator which only ever yields a single value?

Tags: c++, c++17

Some STL algorithms (and STL-like algorithms one could think up in other contexts) take  their inputs via iterators. I sometimes find myself wanting to pass a (const) iterator as one of their inputs which just keeps yielding the same value (or const reference to the same value in memory). You can use that, for example, to implement `std::fill` using `std::copy_n` and `std::distance` (assuming you have the end of your target).

So, does the standard library or one of the TS'es have this anywhere (C++17 or earlier)?

**Note:** I'm not talking about a const iterator, but rather an iterator which never advances and keeps yielding the same thing.

Comment: Which "STL algorithms" are you referring to? Pretty much all I know of will, indeed, advance or otherwise compute something related to the iterator. There would be no point in declaring a library function that takes an iterator value, only to dereference it, and do nothing with it otherwise. I think you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: See edit.

Comment: Your edit does nothing to explain which specific "STL algorithms" you're looking at.

Comment: If you try to pass a non-incrementable/decrementable iterator to a function which needs to advance said iterator then it's just not going to work.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: Actually I gave an invalid example before. Let's try another one.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a class implementing a [forward iterator interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator), and whose dereference operator returns your single value.

Answer (score 0):

This example implements the most simple iterator interface, std::iterator.

The ssize_t argument in the signature is the type to use for differences, because even that is not fixed in the STL :)

How many values it returns is defined by the behavior of operator == in conjunction with the value returned by the end() method.

```
template <typename E>
class IteratorExample
{
    ...

    struct StlIterator
    {
        ...

        const E & operator * ()
        {
            ...
        }

        const E * operator -> ()
        {
            return &(operator * ());
        }

        StlIterator & operator ++ ()
        {
            ...
        }

        StlIterator & operator ++ (int)
        {
            ...
        }

        bool operator == (const StlIterator &other)
        {
            ...
        }

        bool operator != (const StlIterator &other)
        {
            return (operator == (other)) == false;
        }

        typedef E value_type;
        typedef size_t difference_type;
        typedef E * pointer;
        typedef E & reference;
        typedef std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    };

    StlIterator begin() const
    {
        return StlIterator(...);
    }

    StlIterator end() const
    {
        return StlIterator(...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Isn't std::iterator going to be deprecated in C++17?

Comment: Yes, but we don't know yet whether there will be a new convenience mechanism replacing the iterator traits, or we will actually have to write tons of boilerplate for each and every iterator...

Comment: Just modernized it for you :)

Comment: To be honest, I just modernized it for myself in my real actual code so I don't get a warning once c++ 17 is the new standard 

Comment: I actually don't understand the method taking `ref<Iterator>`. Is that `std::ref`? where does the Iterator type come from? Where is the `iter` field? How can a field and a parameter have the same name?

Comment: That was a leftover that I have removed soon after posting the answer :)

Comment: Oh, missed that on top :)

Comment: Now it's gone. Was part of my persistent vector implementation I took the code from. Iterator is an actual iterator implementation ported from Java that is used behind the scenes, ref is my own intrusive ref counter I use internally. Just forget that they were there :)

Answer (score 0):

For `copy_n` the first parameter should satisfy requirements of the [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) . However following example is a minimal working implementation that lacks some requirements of `InputIterator`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
template <typename T, T t>
struct It:public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T>
{
    constexpr auto& operator++() const{
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr auto& operator+(size_t) const{
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr auto operator*() const{
        return t;
    }
};


int main(){
 //an iterator with constant value of 1
    It<int,1> in;
    std::vector<int> out;
    std::copy_n(in, 4, std::back_inserter(out));
}
```